# Nav в html, стилизация nav меню

Tags: html, css, responsive

Всем доброго времени суток.

Уже неделю бьюсь с одним вопросом.
Не могу никак сделать меню, вот как на stackoverflow, чтобы оно было фиксировано, все элементы были горизонтально и вертикально выравнены.[image: Вот как должно выглядеть меню]

Я так понимаю, здесь должен быть один общий ul со множеством вложенных li и dropdown menu,

И вот смотрю уже в ютубе сколько разных видео и каждый делает по разному (что логично), но не пойму как делать более правильнее, со стороны будущей адаптацией.

Главный вопрос состоит в том, как выровнять меня полностью по центру блока (height, weight) и как можно сделать контакты друг под другом (номер и адрес) в едином ul или li, так чтобы они были по центру.

Буду очень рад вашей помощи коллеги.

Comment: посмотрите как это реализовано на других сайтах либо фреймверках, и не мучайте себя видеоураками

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так, дальше где что то не помешается стилизовать на соответствующих разрешениях, `@media` в помощь .. `http://webref.ru` тоже поможет разобраться

> смотреть на всю страницу

разумеется что значки я брал с `font-awesome` от фанаря ... не искал такие же

так же на `ru.stackoverflow.com` поле `search`  при фокусе занимает место до логотипа да и сам логотип выполнен в SVG - нету времени в точности делать как на этом сайте

https://jsfiddle.net/t5mxn9s1/28/ - здесь мои попытки

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  background: #fbfbfb;
}

.container {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 50px;
}

span,
i,
b {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 2px;
}

b {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: orange;
}

@media (max-width:1024px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 800px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="container">
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      stackoverflow
    </span>
    <nav>
      <a href="">issues</a>
      <a href="">tags</a>
      <a href="">participants</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="search">
      <form action="">
        <input type="search">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="releated">
      <span>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30/c0c" alt=""><i>3000</i>
      </span>
      <span class="ratio">
        <i><b>.</b> 1</i>
        <i><b>.</b> 11</i>
        <i><b>.</b> 46</i>
      </span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-grav" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-open" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-american-sign-language-interpreting" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-binoculars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой вариант. Если для кросбаузерности надо.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1090px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  display: table;
}

header {
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fafafb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(12, 13, 14, 0.1), 0 1px 6px rgba(59, 64, 69, 0.1);
}

.header {
  display: table-cell;
}

.logo {
  background: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f');
  height: 38px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-position: 0 -495px;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.menu-item+.menu-item {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu-item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #eff0f1;
}

a.menu-item {
  color: #535a60;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.search {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

input {
  padding: .5rem;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #c8ccd0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #3b4045;
}

input:hover,
input:active,
input:visited {
  position: relative;
  border-color: rgba(0, 149, 255, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #e4e6e8, 0 0 2px rgba(0, 149, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="warapper">
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <a href="/" class="logo"></a>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="/" class="menu-item">Вопросы</a>
        <a href="/" class="menu-item">Метки</a>
        <a href="/" class="menu-item">Участники</a>
      </div>
      <div class="search">
        <input class="input-search" type="search" value="Поиск...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь основные моменты понятны.

Comment: При mt 100px у меня съезжает всё меню, хотя значение задаю другой секции которая находится уже под меню, это как так ?)

Comment: что такое mt? и как меню съезжает ? покажите пример кода